# Composing functions (i.e., replacing a placeholder with a tensor)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to connect two functions: first I define `f(x)`, then I define `g(t)`, and finally I need to set that `x = g(t)`.

MWE

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

session = tf.Session()

# f(x)
x = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,4], dtype=tf.float64)
f = tf.square(x)

# g(t)
t = tf.placeholder(shape=[None,2], dtype=tf.float64)
g = tf.matmul(t,np.ones((2,4)))

session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
t_eval = np.asmatrix(np.random.rand(10,2))

# f(g(t))
session.run(f, {x: session.run(g, {t: t_eval})})

# but I want to do (does not work because I need to assign a value to placeholder x)
x = g
session.run(f, {t: t_eval})
```

Basically I want to replace placeholder `x` with tensor `g`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `x` in your code at all.

```
f = tf.square(g)  # replace your definition of f with this
session.run(f, {t: t_eval})
```